# How to select ids which contain special characters?

Tags: css, html

I'm working with an HTML piece that I cannot modify. One of the ids in the document is:

```
<div id="a>span.tex"> ... </div>
```

This is perfectly valid [HTML5 syntax for ids](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute), however, it is not possible to select this id in CSS without having troubles with `>` and `.` characters.

How can I select this id in CSS?

Comment: While it may be perfectly valid, I think any halfway intelligent person reviewing your code will ask you to change it. Just because something is valid or allowed it does not mean it's a good idea to use it!

Comment: Yes, as I said, I cannot modify the document, I'm just writing one CSS module.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can escape special characters with a backslash:

```css
#a\>span\.tex {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="a>span.tex"> Some funky ID </div>
```

You can even use backslashes within your ID as long as you escape them with another backslash:

```css
#a\\span\\tex {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="a\span\tex"> Some funky ID </div>
```

In fact, lots of crazy strings are valid IDs in HTML5

```css
#\¯\\\_\(\ツ\)\_\/\¯ {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="¯\_(ツ)_/¯"> ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ - but why would you? </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

use this:

```
div[id="a>span.tex"] {
    style here;
}
```

this will select div with id equal to your id

Comment: That's an attribute selector, possibly much slower than a proper ID selector.