# How can I change the text inside my dynamically created button's <span> with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have reviewed [How can I change the text inside my <span> with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7222195/how-can-i-change-the-text-inside-my-span-with-jquery) to get where I am. However, that does not cover dynamically created buttons.

I am creating buttons dynamically which contain a label.

```
$("<button type='button' id='" + this.patExeId 
                + "' name='exerciseMachine' class='btn exeBtn btn-large col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-3 m-1 p-3' "
                + "value='" + this.exeName + "'>" + this.exeName + " <span class='label label-light label-as-badge'>0</span></button>").appendTo($("#allExercises"));
```

[image]

The three "this.patExeId" values are

- OA==
- Mg==
- Mw==

I want to update the label as exercise sets are completed. I am using this test code that is triggered when the button is clicked:

```
$('#'+$(this).attr('id')+ ' span').html('3');
```

This is triggering an error shown in the console log:

```
jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #OA== span
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40096448/how-to-select-ids-which-contain-special-characters You have special characters on that id and they made it an invalid selector. Change those == or follow the link I suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since in your case you are crafting a selector like `#id span` but the element you are using to grab the id is `this` so you can just make it simpler and directly select an element inside that one using `find()`

```
 $(this).find('span').html('3');
```

But to better address your first concern, you were using a selector with an id containing special characters. The `=` has a special meaning in css so it requires to be escaped if you need it to include it literally. To make a very simple example showing that, if you had an element with id `#0==` you should use the following selector:

```
$('#O\\=\\=')
```

And this would be an alternate solution to your problem just for the sake of showing my point:

```
$('#' + $(this).attr('id').replace(/=/g, '\\=') + ' span').html('3');
```

Comment: I added <span class='sr-only'>Sets completed</span></button> so I adjusted your very complete answer to  $(this).find('span:first').html('3');